# How can I check pronunciation of speech?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am working on a project in which the program would get the speech input and then check if its pronunciation is correct (I am using it for a language learning website).
I was trying to use google translator for checking the pronunciation but I think that it doesn't have that function. Any ideas?

Here is my voice recognition script:

```
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx3

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer() 

while True:
    try:
        with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
            audio = recognizer.listen(mic) 

            text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            text = text.lower()
            print(text)
```

So again I need somenthing that would check word pronunciation.

Comment: This should not be solvable with a "simple" speech recognition API since their goal is the opposite: map as many pronunciations as possible to the same result.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```py
import pyttsx3

import speech_recognition as sr

engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")

voices = engine.getProperty("voices")

engine.setProperty("voice", voices[1].id)


def speak(audio):
    
    engine.say(audio)
    
    engine.runAndWait()


def takeCommand():
    
    listener = sr.Recognizer()
    
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        
        print("Listening.......")
        
        listener.pause_threshold = 1
        
        listener.energy_threshold = 400  # This will listen to the louder voice only, so all you need to do is to speak loudly to give the command.
        
        audio = listener.listen(source, timeout=1, phrase_time_limit=10)  # It will give you ten seconds to give the argument otherwise it will run again
        
        try:
            
            print(" Recognising.....")
            
            query = listener.recognize_google(audio, language="en-in")  # Here you can choose the language of your choice
            
            print(f" User said --> {query} \n")
            
        except Exception as e:
            
            # print(e)
            
            print("Sorry I didn't Recognise. Please say it again.....")
            
            return "None"
        
        return query

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    speak("Hello boss, How're you?")
    
    while True:
        
        takeCommand()
```

Comment: Thank you so mutch for your help, but I don't know why I get this error in line 6 (engine.setProperty("voice", voices[1].id)), this is the error : IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Nevermind, I solved the problem I had to replace [1] with [0]. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: you should describe solution. And you should format it correctly because it is unreadable.

Comment: Sorry for that !  but I will make sure that for the next time I post my solution nicely. I am glad that my solution helped you in your project.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide supporting information and explanations. Also, there's no reason to put an empty line after _every single line in the code_; it makes it difficult to read and will be annoying for those copy-pasting your code who have to remove all those lines.